# why could not pull github branch code to local machine

Tags: git

I want to pull the repo https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate code to my local machine from github now. I swith to the remote 6.x-master branch in google chrome browser in github and find this branch contains source code, but when I want to pull the source code into my local machine using this command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git pull -v
POST git-upload-pack (122 bytes)
From https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate
 = [up to date]      6.x-master         -> origin/6.x-master
 = [up to date]      4.x-master         -> origin/4.x-master
 = [up to date]      5.x-master         -> origin/5.x-master
 = [up to date]      7.x-master         -> origin/7.x-master
 = [up to date]      porting-to-firefox -> origin/porting-to-firefox
Already up to date.
```

tell me already up to date, but my local machine did not contain any source code:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git branch
* 6.x-master
  7.x-master
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% ls
README.md
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fetch the github remote `6.x-master` source code into my local machine? I also tried this command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git pull origin 6.x-master
From https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate
 * branch            6.x-master -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

The branch 6.x-master was checkout from 7.x-master in my local machine.

In my work, I always pull local branch A from remote branch A using this command: `git pull origin A`, it seems did not work in this repo. I could not figure out where am I going wrong, It is strange. When I am run git status,shows info like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git status
On branch 6.x-master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/6.x-master' by 16 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

then I run the git push command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git push 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate.git
   5a9ca26..12b9ef2  6.x-master -> 6.x-master
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% git pull
Already up to date.
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% ls
README.md
```

still not have the source code of 6.x-master. I also tried this command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub% git clone -b 6.x-master https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate.git
Cloning into 'crx-selection-translate'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4587, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (85/85), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (77/77), done.
remote: Total 4587 (delta 27), reused 15 (delta 5), pack-reused 4502
Receiving objects: 100% (4587/4587), 1.55 MiB | 734.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2816/2816), done.
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub% cd crx-selection-translate 
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% ls
README.md
```

still not contains the source code.

Comment: I am on A branch right now. @Joe In the repo I am in branch 6.x-master right now.

Comment: Yea I realized I'm trying it with the link you gave

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is very strange and I did not figure out where am I going wrong.@Joe

Comment: Can you just clarify one thing-- I cloned it and switched to the branch 6.x, but it hasn't been updated in years. Are you cloning this for the first time? If so, you should already have the latest changes

Comment: @mkrieger1 that would be ``git branch -a`` I believe. OP only ran ``git branch``

Comment: I clone the repo right now, not for a long time, is it important? the author tell that the branch 6.x-master is open source for all users. @Joe

Comment: the branch 6.x-master was checkout from 7.x-master in my local machine, my local machine only created 2 branch. I just want to fetch the 6.x-master branch right now, should I pull the 6.x-master branch directly from remote repo? @mkrieger1

Comment: @Dolphin if you originally ran ``git clone <url>`` and then ``git checkout <branchName>`` without the "<" and ">" then you already have the latest changes

Comment: But I did not have the 6.x-master branch source code, already have the lastest change?@Joe

Comment: As you are a beginner in Git, I recommend that you *avoid* the `git pull` verb. It adds extra complications before you can understand what is going on. It's meant as a shortcut, an easy way to run `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, but until you know what each of these two commands do, it is, in my opinion, best to use them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> the branch 6.x-master was checkout from 7.x-master in my local machine

And you wrote that the output of `git status` is

```
On branch 6.x-master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/6.x-master' by 16 commits.
```

This tells me that your situation is like this:

```
o <-- origin/7.x-master <-- 6.x-master
|
o
|
[... 14 other commits ...]
|
o
|
o <-- origin/6.x-master
|
o
|
```

But you want:

```
o <-- origin/7.x-master
|
o
|
[... 14 other commits ...]
|
o
|
o <-- origin/6.x-master <-- 6.x-master
|
o
|
```

i.e., your local `6.x.-master` branch is *too far ahead*.

So you have to reset it to `origin/6.x-master`:

```
git checkout 6.x-master
git reset --hard origin/6.x-master
```

---

You also wrote

> [`git pull`] tell me already up to date, but my local machine did not contain any source code

There was no source code because that was the state of the `origin/7.x-master` branch at the time, which you had checked out under the local name `6.x-master`.

Comment: I could fetch the source code from the original author:  `git clone -b 6.x-master https://github.com/lmk123/crx-selection-translate.git `, but I could not fork and fetch code from my own repo. I did not know why would this happen. @mkrieger1

Comment: That sounds like a different question.